# Can't delete file with strange characters in name (NUL symbol?)

Tags: macos, finder

I have two files named `ˇ¡␀␀ˇ¡␀␀␀"9 ␀"9` and `ˇ¡␀␀ˇ¡␀␀` which are not deleted when I empty the trash. I have tried renaming them but they do not accept any changes.

Things I tried:

- renaming the file
- in terminal: rm (a variety of flags)
- Apple Support (1/2 h on the phone, no results)
- restart in safe mode
- disk repair

Nothing works. Even worse, Dropbox synced one of these to my second Mac and now I can't get rid of it there as well.

Comment: if you delete the synced one from the dropbox web interface maybe it will delete it for you :)

Comment: No it doesn't unfortunately :(

Comment: it depends somwhat on wether those `␀` are `\u0000` or `\u2400`

Comment: if osx has `find` you could try `find -delete` from inside the recycle bin, `find -delete` is like `rm -r ./` so be careful

Comment: I could permanently delete the file on Dropbox' Web interface. But it does not disappear on my local machine. What does depend on the chart?

Comment: If the file can be deleted easily.

Comment: Actually I also tried find -delete but it didn't work either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40723/discussion-between-jasen-and-kai).

Answer (score 0):

(I'm ignoring the "osx" tag, since I don't have an OSX machine to check this on.  However, I believe OSX's BSD heritage will cause the information in this answer to be applicable.)

As a person who like sthe command line, I would suggest trying to use the tab completion, and/or wildcards.  Pressing the tab key may be able to help figure out how to finish the file name.

However, I understand that may not work quite so well.  So, here's another approach:

> Terminal: rm (a variety of flags)

This sounds good.  What flags did you try with `rm`?  I suggest that you could try:

`rm -i *`

Then rm should try to delete every single thing.  The `-i` causes `rm`'s "interactive mode" to prompt you about every single file.  So if there are files in the same directory, which you want to keep, then you simply say "n" for those files.

Comment: Thanks, but the -i flag doesn't make a difference: `remove ˇ¡␀␀ˇ¡␀␀? y; rm: ˇ¡␀␀ˇ¡␀␀: Invalid argument`